# Game Theory - $3\times3 $Matrix - Mixed Strategy

Tags: matrices, game-theory

I am trying to solve the following $3\times4$ game:
\begin{array}{c|rrrr}
& A & B & C & D \\\hline X & -3 & 5 & 2 & -1 \\ Y & 4 & -1 & 1 & -3 \\ Z & -1 & -3 & -3 & 0  
\end{array}
I know that the optimal (mixed) strategy for the columns is $$\left(\frac 15A,\ 0\cdot B,\ \frac15C,\ \frac 35D\right)$$

How do I go about finding the optimal (mixed) strategy for the rows? I know how to do this using linear programming but I am looking for a technique that will be quicker. I also know how to do this for $2\times2 $ matrices but I am not sure how to extend this to $3\times3 $ matrices.

I suspect the subgame that needs to be realised is:
\begin{array}{c|rrrr}
& A & C & D \\\hline X & -3 & 2 & -1 \\ Y & 4 & 1 & -3 \\ Z & -1 & -3 & 0  
\end{array}

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: This is a $3\times 4$ game.

Comment: It is but as the column strategy for B is 0 I thought it could be reduced to a 3×3 subgame?

Comment: Yes, this is ok. But in the first line you need to correct it. Does not matter. You need to find an equalizing strategy $(x,y,z)$ with $x+y+z=1$ for the row player , I do not think that there is a faster way than this. You can find the value of the game to be $v=4/5$ and then calculate $(x,y,z)A=v$

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. I will give that a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to obtaining the reduced $3\times 3$ matrix, you did fine. Now, the optimal strategy of the rows player is an *equalizing* strategy, giving him the value of the game against any strategy of the opponent (column player). The value $v$ of the game can be calculated from the optimal strategy of the column player, if we pair this optimal strategy against any strategy of the rows player. So, for example against strategy $X$ $$v=-3\frac15+2\frac15-\frac35=-\frac45 $$ So, you need to solve \begin{cases}-3x+4y-\phantom{3}z&=-\frac45\\\phantom{-}2x+\phantom{3}y-3z&=-\frac45\\-\phantom{2}x-3y+0z&=-\frac45\\\phantom{-2}x+\phantom{3}y+\phantom{3}z&=1\end{cases}

---

Just to compare your result, by standard algebraic operations you can find $$(x,y,z)=\frac1{55}\left(17,\ 9,\ 29\right)$$

Comment: Thanks Jimmy, that all makes sense. Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy, that's what I got. Again, much appreciated.